# grails - min / max constraints fail for float?

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-orm

I have this class:

```
class SomeClass {

    float percent

    static constraints = {
        percent(min:1.0F, max:100.0F)
    }
}
```

When I start the app I get the error:

```
Parameter for constraint [min] of property [percent] of class [class SomeClass] must be the same type as property: [float]
```

Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using small `f` instead of `F`:

```
static constraints = {
    percent(min:1.0f, max:100.0f)
}
```

or

try changing the type of `percent` to `Float`, then 1.0F should be valid

Comment: this is what I tried in the first place. This had the same result. I found an example in the docs with the big letter F - that's why I wrote it like this

Comment: try changing the type of `percent` to `Float`, then `1.0F` should be valid